# Determine if a Rectangle is Inside, Overlaps, Doesn't Overlaps Another Rectangle

Tags: geometry, rectangles

Using the center's x- and y-coordinates, width and length of each rectangle, determine if the second rectangle is inside, overlaps or doesn't overlap the first rectangle.

I know that if I divide the width or height by 2, I will get the reach of both sides of rectangle, horizontally and vertically. I can't seem to come up with a formula to solve for each condition.

Here's the list of variables I'm using:

Rectangle 1: x1, y1, width1, height1
Rectangle 2: x2, y2, width2, height2

Here's the formulas I'm coming up with:

The absolute value of the horizontal distance = x1 - x2
The absolute value of the vertical distance = y1 - y2

Or is it better to subtract the smaller number from the larger one?

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: You may possibly need more variables , as in your case , the rectangles can be rotated , which can consequently yield more than $1$ answer . Or are you assuming that the sides are parallel to the axes ?

Comment: Yes, the sides will be parallel to the axis. Rotation won't be necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If any of the following are true, the rectangles don't intersect, otherwise they do:
$$x_1+\frac{w_1}{2} < x_2-\frac{w_2}{2}$$
$$x_1-\frac{w_1}{2} > x_2+\frac{w_2}{2}$$
$$y_1+\frac{h_1}{2} < y_2-\frac{h_2}{2}$$
$$y_1-\frac{h_1}{2} > y_2+\frac{h_2}{2}$$

**Edit**

For the second rectangle to be inside the first, all of the following must be true:

$$x_2+\frac{w_2}{2} \le x_1+\frac{w_1}{2}$$
$$x_2-\frac{w_2}{2} \ge x_1-\frac{w_1}{2}$$
$$y_2+\frac{h_2}{2} \le y_1+\frac{h_1}{2}$$
$$y_2-\frac{h_2}{2} \ge y_1-\frac{h_1}{2}$$

Comment: What conditions will occur when the rectangle is completely inside?

Comment: It works for each condition now. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

1- You can calculate x distance and y distance by writing $x_1 - x_2$ or $x_2 - x_1$ (it's depend on the bigger number), and it's the same in y distance.

2- You can use this formal ( xDistance $\leq (w_1 - w_2)/2$ and same her with y). from this point you can conclude that the rectangle is inside.

3- Overlap: the same as 2-step, but instead of $-$ write $+$